# How to create delegate to the button click in code behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, delegates, webforms

I have DataList which contains different fields. One of them is next DataList. This inner DataList contains button. And now I would like to bind data for the inner DataList in code behind in OnItemDataBound method. And I need to write there delegate for button. How can I do it? I find the button as the follow:

```
 ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn_down"))
```

And now I would like somehow to define what it should do

And it's important I don't want to use:

```
((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn_down")).Click +=new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

as I need to use some data from OnItemDataBound in this 'Click' function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, 
I found a solution:

```
((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn_up")).Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs args) {});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn_down")).Click +=new EventHandler(btn_Click);  

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Edit, if you need a custom event handler instead of the default one:

```
((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn_down")).Click += new EventHandler(delegate(Customer Parameters Here) {});   

private void btn_Click(Customer Parameters Here)
{
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I need to it inside the function OnItemDataBound as I need to use some data from there

Comment: I edited my answer to account for the ability to pass data from your OnItemDataBound event.